# pass value child window to parent [fancybox]

Tags: php, jquery, yii, fancybox

this is link to active fancyBox

```
<a class="demo-select fancybox.ajax" id="select-demo-vdo" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("/admin/default/listProgram",array("user_id"=>$user_id));?>">select demo video</a>
<input type="text" id="demo-video-id" name="demo_video" value="" />
```

AND This is My Script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".demo-select").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 900,
        maxHeight   : 900,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '80%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',

    });
      });
    </script>
```

In List program view

```
foreach($lists as $file){
     echo "<a href='#' class='thumbnail' onClick='selectVideo($file->id)'>"; 
     echo "$file->name";
     echo "</a>";
}

 <script type="text/javascript">
       function selectVideo(id){
          $("#demo-video-id").val(id);
          parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
       }

</script>
```

Problem is::  demo-video-id was updated But FancyBox not close. How to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed Problem layout before active jquery has facybox script and layout show in facybox has script too. Must delete script in layout was showed in facybox.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$.fancybox.close();`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined

Comment: Try `parent.$.fancybox.close();`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: closeFancybox is not defined

Comment: fixed Problem layout before active jquery has facybox script and layout show in facybox has script too.